# Kiel oni diras „just for the sake of it“ esperante?

Tags: translation

Jen kelkaj ekzemploj:

> *One shouldn’t combine words in Esperanto just for the sake of it.*
>
> *We drove around town just for the sake of it.*

Mi eĉ ne scias kiel serĉi tion en vortaro. En la bulgara, ni diras *„просто така“*, kiun oni povus traduki pli-malpli tiel:

> *simple tiel*

…sed mi ne scias ĉu tio havas la saman signifon en Esperanto. Kiel do diri tion ĝuste?

Comment: It's not 100% clear to me what "for the sake of it" means in this context. Benson has some interesting alternatives under "sake" but nothing specifically for "for its own sake" or "for the sake of it."

Answer (score 7):

Laŭ mia scio ne ekzistas tradicia, fiksita esprimo por tio en Esperanto.
Depende de la kunteksto, precipe laŭ tio, ĉu oni aprobas la dirataĵon aŭ ne, oni povas ĝin esprimi laŭ la jenaj manieroj:

> One shouldn’t combine words in Esperanto just for the sake of it.

"Oni ne kombinu vortojn en Esperanto **sen sufiĉa/vera/bona kialo**.

> We drove around town just for the sake of it.

Ni vage veturis tra la urbo **sencele/simple pro emo**.

Estas interese, la germana havas la saman esprimon kiel la bulgara: *einfach so* "simple tiel", kaj la pola similan: *(po prostu) tak o* "(simple) tiel jen". Mi ĵus iomete serĉis, kaj foje oni povas trovi tiun esprimon proksimume en la signifo ĉi tie celata ankaŭ en Esperanto, unu fojon eĉ e Zamenhof (en la traduko de *La Revizoro*):

> Nu, tute egale. Mi ja nur simple tiel diris. Bone, estu sesdek-kvin rubloj

Do, estus interese ekscii, ĉu ankaŭ aliaj lingvoj esprimas tion simile, tiam oni povus ja sen granda ĝeno ekuzi la simplan ***simple tiel***.

Answer (score 4):

Mi dirus *"sennecese"* aŭ *"senkiale"* en tiu kunteksto. Tion mi plurfoje renkontis en libroj kaj rete.

Kvankam en la rusa oni ankaŭ uzas esprimon *"просто так"* (*"simple tiel"*), mi dubas, ke ĝi havas sencon en Esperanto. :)

Answer (score 2):

In that situation I say *nur tial.*

Comment: Ĉu tio ne estas preskaŭ rekta traduko de la angla *„just because“*? Ŝajnas al mi, ke ĝi ne havas la saman sencon en Esperanto? Aŭ ĉu mi malpravas?

Comment: Jes, ĉi tiu frazo ŝajne havas la saman problemon, kiel _"simple tiel"_ - ambaŭ fakte estas rektaj tradukoj de stabilaj esprimoj en naciaj lingvoj. Do, ambaŭ povas esti nekompreneblaj por esperantistoj el aliaj landoj.

Comment: Efektive, estas pli versxajne ke gxi estas rekta traduko el la germana - Warum? Darum! --- Why? For that reason!  ---- Ne funkcias en la angla.

Comment: Kaj ne temas pri nura elpensajxo mia. Jen el La Ondo De Esperanto: *Nu, ankaŭ vi mizerus, se ĉirkaŭkola ŝnuro vin strangolus — sed ne nur **simple tial**. Ne, ne — temis pri voĉo, voĉeto, apenaŭ aŭdebla, sed al tiuj, kiuj orelojn posedas*